# Why doesn't my Tab Bar show up in the simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar controller that controls 4 view controllers.  When I run the simulator, the tab bar doesn't show up.  I created the tab bar controller in a single page application by dragging it from the object library, then creating segues with `ctrl-drag` for views that had already been created.

I do not have a navigation controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I did not have the Tab Bar Controller selected as `Is Initial View Controller` in the `Attributes Selector`.  After checking this box, the tab bar showed up at the bottom of the simulator.

[image]